# Internet Explorer 11 - Process per tab

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I've found various resources such as [this one](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/askie/2009/03/09/opening-a-new-tab-may-launch-a-new-process-with-internet-explorer-8-0/) stating that in previous versions of Internet Explorer, IE can be configured to use a process per tab upto a certain number of processes by using the registry key:

HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main – TabProcGrowth (string or dword)

I have tried setting this to both string and dword types with decimal values such as 5 or 20 on Windows 10 64bit with IE 11 (11.589.10586.0) to no apparent affect whilst observing in Windows Task Manager.  I expect separate Internet Explorer processes to show per tab in the same way as when I open the developer tools a new process appears.

How is this controlled in IE11?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It transpires that the above registry key can and should work but we saw inconsistent behaviour across some machines in whether it would take effect.  However it did take effect in IE11 on some.  In addition to this the functionality changed in IE11 from IE10.

For programmers, Now if you perform a Window.Open from a website the popup Window that opens runs in the same process as the parent whereas previously it spawned a new process.  To achieve the old semantics you need window.open to be an anchor tag with the full url and target="_blank"